# mega drop down SharePoint 2013 - Any more third party tool

Tags: managed-metadata, third-party-software, menu

Im looking for a mega dropdown menu to use in a sharepoint 2013 project.
I'm happy to use a third party one like this one [archetonomy](http://www.archetonomy.com/)

But i need some other similar ones to compare too but can't find any.
I would appreciate if can find more of this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If you're comfortable with a bit of JavaScript and CSS you can put your own together for free that is based on SharePoint's out of the box navigation.

Here are two resources to get you started:

http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2013/03/how-to-achieve-a-mega-menu-using-out-of-the-box-navigation-in-sharepoint-2013-and-jquery/
http://blog-aspc.azurewebsites.net/so-whats-on-the-megamenu/

Answer (score 0):

I will dare say that Archetonomy is the only company out there who sell this component commercially.
I haven't been able to find any other company who provides this component. Not even on CodePlex.

Most will either buy Archetonomy's (because it is a complete product that you just install and it works) or develop their own (as @Submits suggests).