# Drop down menu in SharePoint 2013 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have got opportunity to work on SharePoint 2013 Foundation version and i noticed there is no publishing template available and thus no navigation. Is there any trick or way I can make drop down menu for the site.

Comment: By Publishing template, do you mean to create a Publishing Portal Site?

Comment: And what type of drop-down menu are we talking about?

Comment: Asad like in Server we find publishing but i know in foundation we dont have so thats why navigation is not there...all i am asking is drop down menu in SharePoint 2013 Foundation

Answer (score 0):

There's no drop down in the Foundation version. If you want this, you need to revert to javascript.

Here's somewhere to start:
[mega drop down SharePoint 2013 - Any more third party tool](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/139336/mega-drop-down-sharepoint-2013-any-more-third-party-tool)